# Convert number to array

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to convert a number into digits and save in an Array using VBScript.

For instance, if i have a number '5508426' then I want to make that as

```
A[0] = '5'
A[1] = '5'
A[2] = '0'
A[3] = '8'
A[4] = '4'
A[5] = '2'
A[6] = '6'
```

Can anyone help me in this, please?

Answer (score 4):

Create a suitable sized array and fill it with the digits obtained by Mid():

```
>> s = "5508426"
>> ReDim a(Len(s) - 1)
>> For i = 0 To UBound(a)
>>     a(i) = Mid(s, i + 1, 1)
>> Next
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, "-")
>>
5-5-0-8-4-2-6
```

You may think about data types - strings vs. numbers - determine what you have as input and what you want as elements, and then throw in some CStr() and/or CInt()/CLng()/CDbl().